# How to only retrieve the tag I specify using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x

I just want the written text out of this website: https://algorithms-tour.stitchfix.com/ so I can put it in Word doc and read it.

When I run the code, I get all the html and the tags, at the very end I get what I want, but I just want to separate the text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://algorithms-tour.stitchfix.com"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
item = soup.find_all("p")
print(item)
```

Is there a way to get just

content

so I can clean it up some more?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for this.  If you only want text found within `p` tags, you can do this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://algorithms-tour.stitchfix.com"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
items = soup.find_all("p")

result = []
for item in items:
    result.append(item.string)

print(result)
```

**Note** that `soup.find_all` returns an *iterable* list, and not a single object.

An alternative, and easier method is to just use `soup.get_text`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://algorithms-tour.stitchfix.com"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.get_text())
```